# Как сделать несколько контейнеров, находящихся рядом друг с другом?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Я хочу сделать общий контейнер #profile-container, в котором слева будут profile-info, profile-details, profile-ratings контейнеры (и всё, что в них лежит), расположенные друг под другом, а справа от них другие контейнеры, которые у меня и не получается добавить. Дело в том, что как бы я их не добавлял, они оказываются под первыми тремя контейнерами (profile-info, profile-details, profile-ratings), а не справа от них. Что делать?

```js
function fetchData() {
  const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
  
  fetch(`https://api.saienterprises.ru/v2/apiTeslaCraft/${username}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {

      const profile = data[0].profile;
      
      const profileContainer = document.getElementById('profile-container');
      const profileNickname = document.getElementById('profile-nickname');
      const profilePicture = document.getElementById('profile-picture');
      profilePicture.src = profile.avatarImageUrl;
      const profileDetails = document.getElementById('profile-details');
      const ratingsContainer = document.getElementById('ratings-container');
      const inputContainer = document.getElementById('input-container')
      inputContainer.style.display = 'none';

      profileNickname.textContent = profile.nickname;
      profileDetails.innerHTML = `
      <p>Дата регистрации: ${new Date(profile.registration).toLocaleDateString()}</p>
      <p>Сообщений: ${parseInt(profile.forumData.messages?.replace(/\s+/g, ''), 10) ?? 0}</p>
      <p>Рейтинги: 
        <font color="#62A201">${parseInt(profile.forumData.positiveRatings?.replace(/\s+/g, ''), 10) ?? 0}</font>
        <font color="#767676"> / </font>
        <font color="#2980B9">${parseInt(profile.forumData.neutralRatings?.replace(/\s+/g, ''), 10) ?? 0}</font>
        <font color="#767676"> / </font>
        <font color="#D90B00">${parseInt(profile.forumData.negativeRatings?.replace(/\s+/g, ''), 10) ?? 0}</font>
      </p>
      <p>Достижений: ${profile.achievements}</p>
      <p>Баллов: ${parseInt(profile.forumData.points, 10) ?? 0}</p>
      <p>Звание: ${profile.rankForum}</p>
    `;
    


      const profileRatings = profile.ratings;
      const allRatings = Object.entries(profileRatings).map(([rating, values]) => ({
        rating,
        received: parseInt(values["Получено"].replace(/\s+/g, ''), 10),
      }));
      
      allRatings.sort((a, b) => b.received - a.received);
      
      const topThreeRatings = allRatings.slice(0, 3);

      // Добавление рейтингов в одну строку
      ratingsContainer.innerHTML = '';

      function appendRatingElement(imagePath, received) {
        const container = document.createElement("div");
        container.classList.add("rating-container");
      
        const img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = imagePath;
        img.classList.add("rating-image");
      
        const label = document.createElement("p");
        label.textContent = received;
        label.classList.add("rating-label");
      
        container.appendChild(img);
        container.appendChild(label);
      
        ratingsContainer.appendChild(container);
      }
      

      for (const { rating, received } of topThreeRatings) {
        const imagePath = `./rating-icons/${rating.toLowerCase()}.png`;
        appendRatingElement(imagePath, received);
      }
      
      profileContainer.style.display = 'block';
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
}

#profile-info, #profile-details {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  text-align: center;
}

#profile-container {
  display: none;
}

#profile-info {
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

#profile-details {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#profile-nickname {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#profile-picture {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

input {
  padding: 8px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rating-container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  
  width: 6vw;
  height: 7vh;
}

.rating-image {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.rating-label {
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Профиль TeslaCraft</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="input-container">
      <h1>Информация о профиле<br>на сервере TeslaCraft</h1>
      <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Введите свой никнейм">
      <button onclick="fetchData()">Продолжить</button>
    </div>
    <div id="profile-container">
      <div id="profile-info">
        <h2 id="profile-nickname"></h2>
        <img id="profile-picture" src="" alt="Profile-picture">
      </div>
      <div id="profile-details"></div>
      <div id="profile-ratings">
        <p><b>Самые получаемые рейтинги</b></p>
        <div id="ratings-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

оберни каждую тройку блоков в ещё один div, а блоку #profile-container пропиши в стилях display:flex